# Trying to get recognize a class instance in roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I’m writing a Visual Studio Extension, and I want to get the Type of a variable by its name and location.

For instance:
There’s a C# code:

```
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
     var flagMick = true;
     Console.WriteLine(""Hello, World!"");
   }
}
```

I am able to communicate with the ExpressionEvaluator and the DTE, I am able to read data off the snapshot and understand its location. I have the specific location but:

I don't want to "relearn" c# parsing, that's what Roslyn is supposed to be for.

So I want my extension to recognize the type of “FlagMick” , given its name and location on the screen.

How can I do that with Roslyn?

Comment: what do you mean with *"name and location on the screen"*? Are you referring to the actual X-Y coordinates?

Comment: the type would be inferred (in this instance since it is a `var`) from the assignment from the right side of the `=` operator.  I'm not sure what this has to do with it's location on the screen.  Possibly you mean location in code?

Comment: name is the name of he param as in flagMick and the location is the Position I received from the TextView.

Comment: https://github.com/SLaks/Ref12/blob/master/Ref12.Roslyn/Services/RoslynSymbolResolver.cs#L16-L18

Comment: hey @Slaks, thanks for the answer, I wish you would open an answer so i could comment there: I am having accessibilty issues:'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Text.TextExtensions.GetOpenDocumentInCurrentContextWithChanges(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Text.SourceText)' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: @MickeyPerlstein: What version of Roslyn are you using?

Comment: @SLaks the version of Assembly Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll is 0.7.0.0

Comment: Did you add a reference to Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.Text.dll?

Comment: @SLaks I cannot find that Dll. I installed the Roslyn as expressed in roslyn.codeplex.com. I downloaded the sdk preview, I looked in my computer folders, I cannot find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
var doc = point.Snapshot.GetOpenDocumentInCurrentContextWithChanges();
var model = doc.GetSemanticModelAsync().Result;
var symbol = SymbolFinder.FindSymbolAtPosition(model, point, doc.Project.Solution.Workspace);
```

You will need a reference to Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.Text.dll, which you can get by adding the [appropriate NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.Text/).